# Understand Linux file system mounting point

Tags: linux, filesystems, mount, partition

(I am new to Linux so this may be a naive question.)

I tried the `df` command. It gives me something like this:

[image]

I know that Linux treats everything as a file.

The first column `Filesystem` and the last column `Mounted on` both look like some fie paths.

So the above output says `/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` is mounted to `/`.

But who mounted the physical disk partition to the `dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` in the first place? If it has been mounted there, why do I have to mount it again to `/`?

As I guess I can mount a physical disk partition to anywhere in the Linux filesystem. Am I wrong on this? Is it true that there only exist a few legal **mount points** in the Linux file system. And things like `dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` is not one of them? And `dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` is totally different from `/`?

Comment: `/dev` contents are not regular files - `/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` refers to some hardware, which is mounted as the root `/` in your system - if you run `mount`, you'll see that something like `udev` is mounted at `/dev`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Everything is a file, but that doesn't mean everything is a mount point.
Files in `/dev` are representation of hardware devices but that doesn't mean they are mounted there, `/dev` itself is a mount point where [devtmpfs](https://lwn.net/Articles/330985/) a virtual filesystem is mounted. When kernel detects a new device (either during the boot process or when a device is plugged in) it creates a new file (sometimes called device node or device file) in `/dev/` representing the device -- for example when you plug in a new USB flash drive, the kernel will create `/dev/sdb` representing the disk and `/dev/sdb1` representing the first partition on it (some userspace tools can also create additional files in `/dev`, udev creates some helper symlinks like `/dev/disk/by-id` etc). As I said, these are not mountpoints and exist even if the device is not mounted, you can mount `/dev/sdb1` (or to be precise you can mount the filesystem on the device) to any (existing) directory you want and by that you are saying "I want to see content of this device (filesystem) here".

So in your example `/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` was created by kernel and it was mounted to `/` during the boot process meaning that content of it is visible in `/`. `/dev/dsk/c0t3d0s0` is not a mountpoint, just a special file created by kernel in `/dev`.

Comment: Thank you for the precise explanation of these concepts.